# Registration confirmation email uses wrong From email address

Tags: civievent

I use Civi 4.7.27 on Drupal.

When using the back-end form to register a contact to an event, and checking the 'Send Confirmation' checkbox, then the 'Receipt From' email address shown is not the one I want.

I tried to change the general Civi's default 'From Address' to the one that I want, but this did not affect this address.

Where is this email address defined to be the default one for sending registration confirmation emails from?

Clarification - when a user registers by himself using the online registration form, he does receive the confirmation email from the correct address, as it is defined in the 'Online Registration' tab of the event configuration page. The problem only happens for manual back-end registrations.

Comment: I think this has changed a bit over the past 6 months and there was a fix some time after 4.7.27 - so it might be that the latest release (5.0.2 but soon to be 5.1.0) might have the behaviour you expect

Comment: I've upgraded to 4.7.31 and the behavior remained the same. But also found the answer - read below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email address which is used by default as the 'Receipt From' address, in the 'Register Participant' back-end form is the FIRST email address (with the highest order) defined in the 'FROM Email Addresses' list. NOT the one that is marked as default.

Moving the address I wanted to use by default, to be the first one on the list - solved the problem.

Comment: Yes, i had to figure the same thing for Contribution back end - it feels like a missing feature that 'default' should be the default. If you want to open a GitLab issue i will get someone to take a look at it

Comment: I am using 5.9.0 under Drupal 7 and this problem persists in one form. I registered someone for an event in the backend and the email was sent out with a from address that was not one of the ones in our list of From addresses. it was an address for the server hosting domain! Instead of it coming from admin@mydomain.org, it came from 1729@serverdomain.com. What's up with that?