# Event registration email comes from number@servername address

Tags: civievent, confirmation

I'm adding an event registraion internally

Find contact record> Go to event tab> register for event

In the confirmation email if I leave the sender as my logged in user details the recipient sees the email address in the number@servername format rather thane firstname.lastname@sitename format

If I send the confirmation from one of the site "from" email addresses training@sitename the recipient sees the address as expected.

If I use the send email action to the same contact using logged in username- from email displays as expected.

D7.66 C5.10.4

Seems to be a similar issue as discussed here
[Registration confirmation email uses wrong From email address](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24758/registration-confirmation-email-uses-wrong-from-email-address)

Anyone seen anything similar?

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem with that: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/713 which was fixed by https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/644 which is marked as fixed in 5.11  Upgrading should fix your issue.

Comment: Cheers Aidian. Will give it a try!

Comment: Aidan, even....